# How to sort a dictionary related to elements from a list collection C#

Tags: c#, list, dictionary, predicate

I have a List (myList) with the name of tables ordered by a sequence. MyObject has 2 properties Table (string) and Sequence (int)

```
List<MyObject>
```

Example:

```
List<MyObject>[0] = MyObject.Sequence = 0, MyObject.Table = "Cat" 
List<MyObject>[1] = MyObject.Sequence = 1, MyObject.Table = "Dog" 
List<MyObject>[2] = MyObject.Sequence = 2, MyObject.Table = "Bird" 
List<MyObject>[3] = MyObject.Sequence = 3, MyObject.Table = "Fish"
```

Then I got a Dictionary with a struct key with has the Table and an EntityObject as value, so this dictionary is already filled with 10 objects values like this

```
dict[0] = key (ID = 1, Table = "Cat" ), EntityObject = Cat 
dict[1] = key (ID = 2, Table = "Dog"), EntityObject = Dog 
dict[2] = key (ID = 3, Table = "Bird"), EntityObject = Bird 
dict[3] = key (ID = 4, Table = "Fish"), EntityObject = Fish 
dict[4] = key (ID = 5, Table = "Cat" ), EntityObject = Cat 
dict[5] = key (ID = 6, Table = "Dog"), EntityObject = Dog 
dict[6] = key (ID = 7, Table = "Cat" ), EntityObject = Cat 
dict[7] = key (ID = 8, Table = "Dog"), EntityObject = Dog 
dict[8] = key (ID = 9, Table = "Cat" ), EntityObject = Cat 
dict[9] = key (ID = 10, Table = "Fish"), EntityObject = Fish
```

So I want to order my dictionary according to the list that contains the table sequence and rebuild the dictionary to have it like this

```
dict[0] = key (ID = 1, Table = "Cat"), EntityObject = Cat 
dict[1] = key (ID = 5, Table = "Cat"), EntityObject = Cat 
dict[2] = key (ID = 7, Table = "Cat"), EntityObject = Cat 
dict[3] = key (ID = 9, Table = "Cat"), EntityObject = Cat 
dict[4] = key (ID = 2, Table = "Dog"), EntityObject = Dog 
dict[5] = key (ID = 6, Table = "Dog"), EntityObject = Dog 
dict[6] = key (ID = 8, Table = "Dog"), EntityObject = Dog 
dict[7] = key (ID = 3, Table = "Bird"), EntityObject = Bird 
dict[8] = key (ID = 4, Table = "Fish"), EntityObject = Fish 
dict[9] = key (ID = 10, Table = "Fish"), EntityObject = Fish
```

I want to **avoid** the loop with a foreach and then recreate a new dictionary  and then copy or clone into the existing one. So, I tried this flying for a moment but I got always the same unsorted list. Maybe I'm missing a Sort or OrderBy method but someone can help to fix this. Suggestions?

```
Dictionary<MyStruct, EntityObject> dict = this.GetDictionary()
    .ToList()
    .FindAll(x => x.Key.Table == myList.Find(y => y.Table == x.Key.Table).Table)
    .ToDictionary(a => a.Key, b => b.Value);
```

**NOTE:**

Guys I already know that a dictionary can't be sorted but if you see my approach, I'm recreating a new dictionary trying to order the elements in memory and assign it to "dict".

> **---EDIT---**

I recently made this modification but nothing still. Help please.

```
Dictionary<MyStruct, EntityObject>
        dict = this.GetDictionary()
                .ToList()
                .OrderBy(x => x.Key.Table == myList
                .Find(z => z.Table == x.Key.Table).Table)
                .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => y.Value);
```

Comment: `I already know that a dictionary can't be sorted` ... `I'm recreating a new dictionary trying to order the elements`, and now you should see what your problem is. A dictionary does not contain order, the order you insert in to the dictionary does not affect how it is layed out in memory. If you want it to behave like you are describing you need to switch to something else like a `OrderedDictionary` or a `KeyedCollection` [like Dennis describes](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19880082/80274).

Answer (score 2):

Dictionaries are intended for fast value search by key. Hence, dictionary optimizes its internal storage for searching purposes, so, basically, dictionaries are unordered data structures. The same is true for other containers, which use hash-based search (like [`HashSet`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)).

When you add item to dictionary, it calculates hashcode of the provided key, and places value into a bucket, that corresponds to the calculated hashcode. It doesn't append value to the end of collection (comparing, for example, to `List<T>`). So, "order" or items is determined by hashcode of the key only.

If you want to preserve some items order (to be more precise, if you want ability to access items by index), and still use dictionary, you need a special implementation, like [`OrderedDictionary`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.ordereddictionary%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) or [`KeyedCollection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132438.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You cannot sort a `Dictionary<K, V>`. It is based on a hash table. The sort order depends on a hash key and the algorithm used. This yields an unpredictable order.

There is a `SortedDictionary<K, V>` but that one is sorted by the key. It's not what you want.

In order to use the sequence number for sorting, you should store them in a dictionary by table name.

```
var tableSequence = new Dictionary<string, int>();
tableSequence.Add("Cat", 0);
tableSequence.Add("Dog", 1);
...
```

Then you can use this information to sort the entity objects:

```
Dictionary<MyStruct, EntityObject> dict = this.GetDictionary();
var orderedList = dict
    .OrderBy(x => tableSequence[x.Key.Table])
    .ToList();
```

Storing this information back to a dictionary would distroy the sort order.

---

There is also the `System.Collections.Specialized.OrderedDictionary`, but that one is not generic. Note: it is ordered, not sorted. This means that the elements are stored in the order you entered them. So basically, you would have to add the pre-sorted elements in a loop, one by one. You can then access the elements either by the index or by the key.